# How to use Where Clause in Exec Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm having a Stored Procedure

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR(10),
    last_name   VARCHAR(10),
    salary      DECIMAL(10,2),
    city        VARCHAR(20),   
)
```

Adding Some Data to the employee Table:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 'Karvendhan',  'Palani',4789,'Agra');
GO

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'Bala',  'Manigandan',8789,'Bombay');
GO

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3, 'Raj' ,  'Kishore',   5567,'London');
GO

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4, 'Prayag',  'Pavithran',  4467,'Bombay');
GO

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (5, 'Selva',  'Kumar',  3456, 'Bombay');
GO

select * from employee;
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEmployeeBasedOnCity
(
    @city VARCHAR(20)
)

AS
BEGIN
    select * from employee where city = @city
END;
```

I'm Executing the Stored Procedure: `exec GetEmployeeBasedOnCity 'Bombay';`

I'm getting the Output:

```
id      first_name       last_name        salary          city
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2       Bala             Manigandan       8789.00        Bombay
4       Prayag           Pavithran        4467.00        Bombay
5       Selva            Kumar            3456.00        Bombay
```

I need to put where clause at the time of `exec GetEmployeeBasedOnCity 'Bombay';`
not inside the Stored Procedure. Kindly assist me...

> Imagine the Query (Rough Expectation)
>
> `exec GetEmployeeBasedOnCity 'Bombay' WHERE salary >5000`

Comment: Stored procedures aren't views and can't be part of queries. If you want to apply additional criteria, you should be looking at views or functions. In fact, given the content of the stored procedure, why don't you simply query against `employee` directly?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Its just an sample sql source code. In the real scenario my stored procedure returns >5000 Records. I need to apply filter in that result without modifying the Stored Procedure...

I saw a link https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/28987/applying-where-clause-to-stored-procedure-result.html but its giving error...

Comment: You **can't** use a stored procedure in a query. Use a function or a view

Comment: @BalamanigandanB as mentioned above - make it a `view` or `function`. You don't have an sp here. You need some source which is somehow pre-filtered, and filtered once more later. SP is not supposed to be a source for other queries. There are other objects which are supposed to: FUNCTION and VIEW.

Comment: Many Service using the Stored Procedure. It's possible to query - without altering or creating a view ? For my local reference purpose I need to filter the data.

Comment: So implement your filtering logic inside of your SP or don't use SP. Actually you don't have here neither SP nor VIEW or FUNCTION - this is an adhoc query (which means "I select what I want right now the way I want to"). Or think more about the filtering **logic** and if it's constant and can be **stored** and being unchanged (excepting values of filtering _arguments_) - then put it into your SP.

Comment: The best option is to refactor the stored procedure, extract the actual code into a view or function and then call this function both from the SP and your code. The other option is to store the results of the stored procedure to a temporary table and then query that table. This is very inefficient though. Perhaps you should rethink the design - *why* do you want to filter the results of the stored procedure? If filtering is a common requirement, why was a stored procedure used at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best approach would be to execute the needed query independently of the stored procedure.  But if you must use the existing stored procedure without changes, you could insert the proc results into a temporary table and then apply additional filters on that table:

```
CREATE TABLE #employee(
    id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR(10),
    last_name   VARCHAR(10),
    salary      DECIMAL(10,2),
    city        VARCHAR(20),   
);

INSERT INTO #employee
    EXEC GetEmployeeBasedOnCity 'Bombay';

SELECT *
FROM #employee
WHERE salary > 5000;
```

Comment: I Have same scenario but my inner SP contain transaction and it will return error
 'The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.', 
I am trying to do same thing

Comment: @S.Deshmukh, I suggest you ask a new question, including the outer and inner proc code.